# How to use JPA criteriaBuilder to search on attributes in a collection of sub-attributes

Tags: jpa, collections, criteria

I have an Entity that maps to a table defined this way:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cmmn_calendar_evnt")

public class CommonCalendarEvent implements java.io.Serializable
{
    private Integer                      cevId;
    private Set<CommonCalendarEventPart> commonCalendarEventParts = new HashSet<CommonCalendarEventPart>(0)

@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "CEV_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getCevId()
    {
        return this.cevId;
    }

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "commonCalendarEvent")
    public Set<CommonCalendarEventPart> getCommonCalendarEventParts()
    {
        return this.commonCalendarEventParts;
    }
}
```

and CommonCalendarEventPart is defined like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cmmn_calendar_evnt_part")

public class CommonCalendarEventPart implements java.io.Serializable
{

    private static final long   serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Integer             ceeId;
    private CommonCalendarEvent commonCalendarEvent;
    private PartParticipant     partParticipant;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "CEE_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getCeeId()
    {
        return this.ceeId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CEE_CEV_ID", nullable = false)
    public CommonCalendarEvent getCommonCalendarEvent()
    {
        return this.commonCalendarEvent;
    }

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CEE_PPT_ID", nullable = false)
    public PartParticipant getPartParticipant()
    {
        return this.partParticipant;
    }

}
```

and finally:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "part_participant")

public class PartParticipant implements java.io.Serializable
{
    private static final long            serialVersionUID         = 1L;
    private Integer                      pptId;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "PPT_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getPptId()
    {
        return this.pptId;
    }

}
```

I want to use the CriteriaBuilder to generate a query finding all CommonCalendarEvent  for a specific Participant ID.

In Hql  it would look something like this: (although I have not confirmed that this Hql is correct either)

```
"from commonCalendarEvent cce  where :pptId in (cce.commonCalendarEventParts.partParticipant.pptId)"
```

I've tried some approaches of what I thought were intuitive attempts at writing a criteriaBuilder approach, but my attempts have resulted in errors ranging from:
“unexpected end of subtree”  to just implementation errors.

```
.....

    CriteriaBuilder builder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();

    CriteriaQuery<CommonCalendarEvent> criteria = builder.createQuery(CommonCalendarEvent.class);

    Root<CommonCalendarEvent> root = criteria.from(CommonCalendarEvent.class);

    Fetch<CommonCalendarEvent, CommonCalendarEventPart> evf = root.fetch(CommonCalendarEvent_.commonCalendarEventParts, JoinType.LEFT);

    Join<CommonCalendarEvent, CommonCalendarEventPart> evj = (Join<CommonCalendarEvent, CommonCalendarEventPart>) evf;

    Join<CommonCalendarEventPart, PartParticipant> evpj = evj.join(CommonCalendarEventPart_.partParticipant);
    List<Predicate> pred = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

    pred.add(builder.equal(evpj.get(PartParticipant_.pptId), pptId));
    criteria.where(builder.and(pred.toArray(new Predicate[] {})));
    return getEntityManager().createQuery(criteria).getResultList();

.............
```

above yields an "unexpected end of subtree" error.

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: Please review the code posted: what is `evf`?

Comment: sorry corrected code.  forgot to add the Fetch<CommonCalendarEvent, CommonCalendarEventPart> evf...  its there now.

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

+1 for using Lazy initialization. The JPA model is Object, or Entity oriented, so you need to get used to thinking in those terms. A `PartParticipant` is not identified by its `id` in JPA, but by the object itself. Assuming you have a list of participants:

```
PartParticipant pp = em.find(PartParticipant.class, 2);
List<PartParticipant> pps = new ArrayList<PartParticipant>();
pps.add(pp);
```

Then you pass that list to the queries. In JPQL:

```
TypedQuery<CommonCalendarEvent> cev = em.createQuery("select cev from CommonCalendarEvent cev join fetch cev.commonCalendarEventParts cce where cce.partParticipant in :pps", CommonCalendarEvent.class);
List<CommonCalendarEvent>  cevs = cev.setParameter("pps", pps).getResultList();
```

Notice the fetch is needed to prevent `LazyInitializationExceptions`.

Knowing the JPQL, the `CriteriaQuery` should follow pretty much the same:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<CommonCalendarEvent> q = cb.createQuery(CommonCalendarEvent.class);
Root<CommonCalendarEvent> r = q.from(CommonCalendarEvent.class);
Join<CommonCalendarEvent, CommonCalendarEventPart> j = r.join("commonCalendarEventParts");
r.fetch("commonCalendarEventParts");
q.select(r).where(j.get("partParticipant").in(pps));
List<CommonCalendarEvent> rs = em.createQuery(q).getResultList();
```

You don't need to do anything special with the fetch other than execute it. As you can see, the query uses the PartParticipant Id.

```
select 
    commoncale0_.CEV_ID as CEV_ID1_0_0_, 
    commoncale1_.CEE_ID as CEE_ID1_1_1_, 
    commoncale1_.CEE_CEV_ID as CEE_CEV_2_1_1_, 
    commoncale1_.CEE_PPT_ID as CEE_PPT_3_1_1_, 
    commoncale1_.CEE_CEV_ID as CEE_CEV_2_0_0__, 
    commoncale1_.CEE_ID as CEE_ID1_1_0__ 
from cmmn_calendar_evnt commoncale0_ 
    inner join cmmn_calendar_evnt_part commoncale1_ on commoncale0_.CEV_ID=commoncale1_.CEE_CEV_ID 
where commoncale1_.CEE_PPT_ID in (?)
```

Comment: very nicely put.   I was about to post that I found that I can't take the Fetch and cast it to a Join, because the Fetch yields a generic join, but the legitimate join yields a "SetJoin"  which is what I needed.  So my solution is to do what you are doing, have both a join and a fetch.  But in my entityManager I get two inner joins on the code.

Comment: 1 question though.  How does the system know to resolve a match on PartParticipant to just the PPTID?   is it because of the "@ID" tag?  if I passed in a PartParticipant that didn't have an ID it wouldn't work right?

Comment: Yes, I think it will strip the ID's from the PartParticipant list and use them. You can create "fake" PartParticipants by just making new ones and setting the id, though if you're going to do that you should be able to change the query to actually accept a list of ID's instead of the PP Entities.

Answer (score 0):

`Fetch<CommonCalendarEvent, CommonCalendarEventPart> evf` is not necessary, and the first join statement should be corrected:

```
Join<CommonCalendarEvent, CommonCalendarEventPart> evj = 
                          root.join(CommonCalendarEvent_.commonCalendarEventParts);
```

The rest of the query seems correct.

Comment: Sorry forgot to put in the line:   Fetch<CommonCalendarEvent, CommonCalendarEventPart> evf  = .....      Its there now.   but even with that, or even if I run the code with a Join and not a fetch.  I get the "unexpected end of subtree" error.

Comment: One must assume that since I am getting Runtime exceptions that the code must have compiled.

Comment: Well, the Fetch is necessary if I want to get the CommomCalendarEventPart data to return in the results.  So YES the Fetch is necessary.  I then recast back to a join so that I can join the rest of the data.     But   Event if I don't do the Fetch, and do a join instead, I still get the same error.  So there must be something that allows me to treat the Collection of CommonCalendarEventParts in the same manner tat the Hql solution would.